# UserManager.FindAsync to use custom Userstore's FindByIdAsync method instead of FindByNameAsync

Tags: asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm using Identity Framework.
When I login to my app, the appUser retrieves the UserManager as follow:

```
Patient patient = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Id, model.Password);
```

As I understand from debugging, UserManager.FindAsync uses the `FindByNameAsync(string userName)` from the UserStore (I have a custom UserStore).

The question is: How to tell UserManager.FindAsync to use the FindByIdAsync method of my custom UserStore instead of FindByNameAsync?

Do I need to also write a custom UserManager?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method in a custom UserManager

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, string>
{
     public override async Task<AppUser> FindAsync(string id, string password)
     {
         var user = await FindByIdAsync(id).WithCurrentCulture();
         if (user == null)
         {
             return null;
         }
         return await CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).WithCurrentCulture() ? user : null;
     }   
}
```